# Java EE 6 Distributed Transaction - Getting JTS5031 Exception with Glassfish v3.0.1

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, java-ee-6, glassfish-3, jts

I'm trying to do a distributed transaction between two PostgreSQL databases. I'm using Glassfish v3.0.1.

In my GlassFish domain I have my two connection pools setup to have a resource type of javax.sql.XADataSource with a class name of org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource.

I'm trying to create an integration test on a stateless EJB method that is hitting both databases. To perform the integration test I am creating an embedded version of glassfish, and looking up the EJB through JNDI.

When I run integration tests that only involve one persistence unit, they are working fine.

This is the first distributed transaction that I'm trying to do, so I'm not sure if everything is set up right.

I'm really not sure about how to find information on how to solve this, as I'm not really sure what the stack is getting at. I've looked at the logs in myDomain/logs and couldn't find anything - are there any other logs? The stack trace is below:

javax.ejb.EJBException: Unable to complete container-managed transaction.
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5002)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4756)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1955)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1906)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:198)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:84)
        at $Proxy101.createAccount(Unknown Source)
        at cheetah.services.impl.**EJB31_Generated_*AccountService*_Intf_***Bean*_.createAccount(Unknown Source)
        at cheetah.services.tests.integration.AccountServiceTest.createAccount_ValidParameters_AccountCreated(AccountServiceTest.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapter.run(JUnit4TestAdapter.java:39)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.run(JUnitTestRunner.java:518)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.launch(JUnitTestRunner.java:1052)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.main(JUnitTestRunner.java:906)
Caused by: javax.transaction.SystemException: org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: JTS5031: Exception [org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL:   vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0 completed: Maybe] on Resource [rollback] operation.  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
        at com.sun.jts.jta.TransactionManagerImpl.commit(TransactionManagerImpl.java:330)
        at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.jts.JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate.commitDistributedTransaction(JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate.java:158)
        at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.commit(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:843)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:4991)
        ... 43 more

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem (CORBA error JTS5031) that turned out to be because glassfish wanted a prepared transaction (which it's never wanted in the 2 years I've been using it) and my dbms (postgres) wasn't configured to use them.

try looking in your postgres logs